# How do I search through a database using a textbox and search button C#?

Tags: c#, database, data-binding

So I want to search through the Area Codes i put in through the database. I put in the Code, then it is suppose to print out the phone numbers and duration under that area code on a multi line text box . This is what I have so far. And yes I'm a beginner and a bad one :D.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'phonecallsDataSet1.Calls_with_Region' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
        this.calls_with_RegionTableAdapter.Fill(this.phonecallsDataSet1.Calls_with_Region);
        tbAreaCode.Text = String.Format("Phone Number" + "\t" + "\t" + "Duration" + "\r\n"
            + "============" + "\t" + "\t" + "=======");
    }

    private void btnSearchAC_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (DataColumn number in phoneCallbindingSource.List)
        {
            if (txtAC.Text == ((int)number["Area Code"]))
            {
                tbAreaCode.Text += ((int)number["Phone Number"]); 
          }
        }
    }
}
}
```

**Error**

> Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type System.Data.DataColumn

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type System.Data.DataColumn

Comment: I believe the Fill should state this.phonecallsDataSet1.Table["Calls_with_Region"]  Is there actually any data in your Dataset?  Also, what line are you getting the error on?

Answer (score 0):

I think querying the database itself to get this information and fill your textbox or listbox with the returned values is a better approach to what u want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so the problem is  you are iterating by Columns instead of rows.  Here is a working example that shows two ways to do the same thing.  One iterates through the DataTable (are you using a DataSet because you have multiple tables?  If you only have one table use a DataTable, if you have multiples use a DataSet). The second uses Linq which I put in because as a beginner it is helpful to get exposure to some of the more useful features of C#.  Make sure to include System.Linq. Just paste this into the Main of a Console app overwriting the initial Main function and you can play with it.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string CurrentAreaCode = "415";// Input from textbox;

    // Setup Mock Dataset
    DataSet ds = new DataSet("Information");
    ds.Tables.Add("AreaCodeInformation");
    ds.Tables[0].Columns.Add("AreaCode");
    ds.Tables[0].Columns.Add("PhoneNumber");
    ds.Tables[0].Rows.Add();
    ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][0] = 415;
    ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][1] = 9252222222;

    // output with row iterator
    Console.WriteLine("Using Iteration of DataTable in DataSet");
    foreach (DataRow number in ds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable())
    {
        if (number["AreaCode"].ToString() == CurrentAreaCode)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(number["PhoneNumber"].ToString());
        }
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Press Enter To Continue...");
    Console.ReadLine();

    // output using Linq
    Console.WriteLine("Using Linq");
    Console.WriteLine((from info 
                       in ds.Tables["AreaCodeInformation"].AsEnumerable() 
                       where info.Field<string>("AreaCode") == CurrentAreaCode 
                       select info.Field<string>("PhoneNumber")).FirstOrDefault());
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```